# Collectors.toMap doesn't compile

Tags: java, java-stream

This code doesn't compile

```
List<String> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println(pairs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.split("=")[0], x -> x.split("=")[1])));
```

Compilation error is: *The method split(String) is undefined for the type Object 
error at System.out.println(pairs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.split("=")[0], x -> x.split("=")[1])));*

But this one compiles fine

```
List<String> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,String> map = pairs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.split("=")[0], x -> x.split("=")[1]));
System.out.println(map);
```

Can someone explain why?

**MORE INFORMATION**

It was intellij 12; jdk1.8.0_11; windows 64

Comment: Both versions compile and run fine on my jdk1.8.0_20.  What version of jdk are you using?

Comment: Can't reproduce either - either you have an old version of the jdk or you are using a different compiler (eclipse?).

Comment: @All: This is reproducible with Eclipse. I am using the new Luna version. The Eclipse compiler shows this compiler error. Using a simple "javac ..." command compiles just fine.

Comment: AFAIK some compilers had a problem with correctly inferring generic types, especially in situations like the first code block. That might explain why some aren't able to reproduce that error. Could you try `Collectors.<String, String, String>toMap(...)` in the first block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versions of IntelliJ make different(Just red lines in source editor in IDE). The code should be compiled by JDK successfully.

IntelliJ 13 is OK for your code. IntelliJ 12 supports lambda expression poorly. I also met similar problems between two versions of IntelliJ when using lambda expression.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are using an IDE (like Eclipse). Eclipse - for example - uses its own compiler and does not utilize the "javac" command (from JDK).

So, I can reproduce your problem, but only with Eclipse. Simply compiling this code on command line with "javac" works just fine.

The problem is very simple: The Eclipse compiler is not able to infer the type `String` for the `collect` method's arguments. So it simply infers `Object` (as this is the type, the compiler can safely assume). And an `Object` does not know the `split` method.

You can force the compiler to know about `String` by explicitely declaring the type inside the lambda:

```
List<String> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println(pairs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap((String x) -> x.split("=")[0], x -> x.split("=")[1])));
```

... or by explicitely declaring the correct types for the geneirc `toMap` method:

```
List<String> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println(pairs.stream().collect(Collectors.<String, String, String> toMap(x -> x.split("=")[0], x -> x.split("=")[1])));
```